# Testing practice an API wrapper without using unittest module

Tags: python, unit-testing

i have wrote an api wrapper which has around 70 endpoints. To test them all

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/V6mkK4dSdh/ 
i have wrote this script without actually usign the unit testing module. Is it a good practice and what are the downsides when compared with unit testing? Really could use some comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is not "testing". This is just checking that "they work".

However, in this context, "work" just means that they don't raise exceptions. That's a requirement, but not even close to "testing". The fact that you endpoint return *some result* does not mean that the result is correct.

Really testing would mean: When I call `f(1, 2)` I expect to get `5` as a response. So, you would need multiple tests, manually written, for each endpoint. Of course, that takes time...